# With only ADD, AND, NOT How do we OR

Tags: lc3

In LC-3, how can I store r1 or r2 into register r3

ld r1, a        ;move the value of a into r1
ld r2, b        ;move the value of b into r2
and r3, r1, r2      ;

halt            ;stop

Comment: With DeMorgan's law?

Answer (score 2):

You can use DeMorgan's law to achieve this.

> X ∨ Y = ¬(¬X ∧ ¬Y)

In LC3 code it's:

```
LD R1, a ;move the value of a into R1
LD R2, b ;move the value of b into R2
NOT R1, R1
NOT R2, R2
AND R3, R1, R2
NOT R3, R3

HALT
```